# Cannot set all violins to the same width in R Plotly

Tags: r, plotly, width, violin-plot

I'm trying to reproduce in R Plotly a 2 categorical variables violin plot that works just fine in ggplot2. But when I set the widths of the individual violins to be the same, using scalemode = "width", as described in the reference (https://plotly.com/r/reference/violin/), it simply wont work. Instead, it shows the widths (violin maximum) proportional to the counts in each category.

Here is an example:

```
# Paths:
path_data = "data/"
path_lib = "renv/library/R-4.1/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/"

# Packages:
require(dplyr, lib = path_lib)
require(readr, lib = path_lib)
require(RColorBrewer, lib = path_lib)
require(plotly, lib = path_lib)

# Dataset:
df = readr::read_csv(paste0(path_data, "nasa_exoplanets.csv")) %>%
         as.data.frame()
attr(df, "spec") = NULL
df_varnames = readr::read_csv(paste0(path_data, "nasa_exoplanets_var_names.csv")) %>%
                  as.data.frame()
attr(df_varnames, "spec") = NULL

# Variables:
cat_var1 = "st_metratio"
cat_var2 = "disc_locale"
cat_var_name1 = (df_varnames %>%
                    dplyr::filter(var == cat_var1))$var_name
cat_var_name2 = (df_varnames %>%
                     dplyr::filter(var == cat_var2))$var_name
num_var = "sy_dist"
num_var_name = (df_varnames %>%
                    dplyr::filter(var == num_var))$var_name

# Adapt the data:
df_plot = df %>%
              dplyr::select(cat_var1,
                            cat_var2,
                            num_var)

# Deal with NA:
df_plot[which(is.na(df_plot[, cat_var1])), cat_var1] = "NA"
df_plot[which(is.na(df_plot[, cat_var2])), cat_var2] = "NA"
df_plot = df_plot[which(!is.na(df_plot[, num_var])), ]

# Levels order:
sorted_levels1 = sort(unique(df_plot[, cat_var1]))
df_plot[, cat_var1] = factor(x = df_plot[, cat_var1],
                             levels = sorted_levels1)
sorted_levels2 = sort(unique(df_plot[, cat_var2]))
df_plot[, cat_var2] = factor(x = df_plot[, cat_var2],
                             levels = sorted_levels2)

# Plot:
my_palette = colorRampPalette(c("#111539", "#97A1D9"))
n_levels2 = length(unique(df_plot[, cat_var2]))
p = plot_ly(
    data = df_plot,
    type = "violin",
    x = ~eval(parse(text = cat_var1)),
    y = ~eval(parse(text = num_var)),
    color = ~eval(parse(text = cat_var2)),
    colors = my_palette(n_levels2),
    spanmode = "hard",
    alpha = 1,
    box = list(visible = FALSE),
    meanline = list(visible = FALSE),
    points = FALSE,
    scalemode = "width"                           ### this doesn't work ###
) %>%
    layout(
        xaxis = list(
            title = paste0("<b>", cat_var_name1, "</b>"),
            titlefont = list(size = 20),
            tickfont = list(size = 18),
            categoryorder = "array"
        ),
        yaxis = list(
            title = paste0("<b>", num_var_name, "</b>"),
            titlefont = list(size = 20),
            tickfont = list(size = 18),
            type = "log"
        ),
        margin = list(
            l = 10,
            r = 10,
            t = 10,
            b = 10
        ),
        legend = list(
            title = list(
                text = paste0("<br><b>", cat_var_name2, "</b>"),
                font = list(size = 18)
            )
        ),
        hoverlabel = list(font = list(size = 16)),
        showlegend = TRUE,
        violinmode = "group"
    )

p
```

data file: https://github.com/rafael747cardoso/Data_Visualization_Gallery/blob/main/data/nasa_exoplanets.csv

How it should be, plotted in ggplot2:

[image: How it should be, plotted in ggplot2]

How it is with R Plotly:

[image: How it is with R Plotly]